# How to convert phone numbers to a standard format?

Tags: android, algorithm, phone-number

I need to develop back-end of an android application in which i will fetch contacts of a user from android phone and check whether any one of his contact is already in by db .
I need a good algorithm to match user contact numbers with number stored in Db.I am storing users number with their country code.`(eg :"911234567890" for Indian number)`.but user will save contacts in different format`(Eg 1234567890,+961 2345 6789,123-456-7890,+911234567890,01234567890 etc)`.How to convert these numbers to a standard  format?

Comment: + would represent 00, remove all other non-numeric characters. It shall give you the phone number if it is valid.

Comment: `+` would not necessarily represent 00 in all countries, though. You need information on the current locale to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: A possible approach is to replace all + with "00" and all " ","-" or "/" with  "". But this doens't solve your problem, as example, you dont need in every case he 00XX prefix. There is alos a problem with +123 (0) 123. I think its a real competition to write a working parser.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

Google's [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) includes functions for parsing, formatting and validating phone numbers.